# Some avatars don't show up and only showing the alt text in the chat

Tags: support, bug, chat, firefox, tor

Today I found my mozilla engine based browser (Mozilla Firefox 52.2.0 (32-bit)<sup>1</sup>) left me with some strange (image) rendering quirks at the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) chatroom:

[image]

As the title says there are only alternate texts for some images rendered, but that screws up the whole `<div>` or `<span>` (I dunno really) rendering.
I suspect it might have something to do with the *"not blocking insecure passive content"* as described here:

[Mixed content blocking in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&as=u&redirectslug=how-does-content-isnt-secure-affect-my-safety&utm_source=inproduct)

Though I didn't find a way to fix that, or what might be the reason (most of the image URL's<sup>2</sup> are using *https* transports anyway).

Is that a known bug? I never experienced that until today.

---

At the dev console I see:

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'm using the Tor browser for various reasons TBH.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Well, I didn't really check **all** of them, just some probes.</sub>

Comment: @Inc. Well, I'm not a web dev crack. Lemme try that.

Comment: @Inc. Updated the question regarding what's shown in the Dev Console. A number of requests are marked with the waning symbol in the _Network Monitor_. Should I post a full protocol for the latter? I can reproduce that all the time now BTW, doesn't look like a _hiccup_.

Comment: There are a couple of gifs in the transcript that are http instead of https like [this one](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6219731#6219731). Not much you can do about that

Comment: @rene It's quite annoying though, and I don't like to change browsers :-/

Comment: Yell at those pesky users that still insist on pasting http links to gifs ...

Comment: @rene Well, I'll go after those systematically right now :-D! I still don't get how that can fail rendering alltogether though (as mentioned I'm not a web dev crack).

Comment: @Inc. THX for your title edit. That describes the problem more clearly.

Comment: The images are loaded by the master-chat.js, a JavaScript file. If firefox determines something goes wrong(in this case loading an image over http instead of https) Firefox kills the current execution of the script. That makes it ends somewhere in the middle of whatever it was doing, in this case it managed to complete some of the html for showing the avatars but not all. If you're lucky, next time it might stop somewhere else, either giving a better or worse result.

Comment: @rene THX for the insight. But something must have been changed up until today (as mentioned, I never experienced that before).